# Where is the mistake - they shows incorrect message

Tags: php, kohana

I created function for my blog, but it not works correctly.
Controller:

```
$id_get = Model::factory('index')->get_id($slug);
$this->template->content = View::factory('index/article')
                    ->set('slug', $mysql_respnse)
        ->set('commentars', Model::factory('index')->find_commentars($id_get));
```

View:

```
    <?php
    if($commentars){
      echo 'There is a commentar!'; 
    }
else{
echo 'There is no any commentar!';
}
    ?>
```

Model:

```
public function get_id($slug){
    $query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT id FROM ieraksti WHERE slug = :slug')
            ->parameters(array(':slug' => $slug))->execute()->as_array();
}
```

Where is the mistake? The script shows 'There is no any commentars!', but I need 'There is a commentar'.

Comment: Maybe there's no commentar in your database?

Comment: There is 3 commentars in my database, where artcl_id is 3 and blog article id is 3.

Comment: What is a 'commentar'? Any chance you mean 'commentary' and 'commentaries' or 'comment' and 'comments'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not return anything in the get_id() method of your model. Therefor $get_id has a value of NULL and so does $commentars.

Comment: Thank you, in model was a mistake, I 1 hour ago corrected this mistake. :)